# Sorting through the logic of available units in a reservation system

Tags: php, mysql, web, logic

I am working on a project where I need to find available units. The relevant information is this:

A table of units with fields id, name, owner, addr, active(boolean), booked(boolean)

A table of reservations with fields  id, unit(tied to unit.id), guest, price, arrival_date, depart_date, checkedin(boolean), checkout(boolean), cleaned(boolean)

The user selects an arrival date and a departure date. From that I need to build a list of available units. I am having trouble thinking through this logically. I am doing this in PHP and so far have this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

//get date
$arrival = '2013-10-1';     //$_POST['arrival'];
$depart =  '2013-10-1';         //$_POST['depart'];

//define arrays
$a = array();
$d = array();

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT arrival, departure FROM reservations WHERE arrival > '".$depart."'");

$i=0;

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $a[] = $row['arrival']; 
    $d[] = $row['departure'];
    echo '  ('.$i.')  ';
    echo $a[$i];
    echo '   ';
    echo $d[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

that yields what I want (the departure date must be before the arrival of some other party.

I also know that the arrival cannot be during a stay.

Can anyone help me out with this? It really me stumped. I don't even necessarily need to see the code; a pseudocode would even be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The available units are the ones that have NO conflicting bookings.

Conflicing bookings are the ones with arrivals (on or) before the desired departure AND with departures (on or) after the desired arrival.

This logic is implemented with a query like this:

```
select unit from unit u 
left join reservations r on r.unit = u.id
and r.arrival <= $departure
and r.departure >= $arrival
where r.unit is null
```